# Does $2 \mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) \preceq \mathrm{Cov}(X, X) + \mathrm{Cov}(Y, Y)$ hold for random vectors?

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

For any two $n$-dimensional random vectors $X$ and $Y$, does the following inequality hold?

$$2 \mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) \preceq \mathrm{Cov}(X, X) + \mathrm{Cov}(Y, Y),$$

where $A \preceq B$ means $A - B$ is positive semi-definite.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y)$ are both $n\times n$ covariance matrices. Just a question for clarity: What is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: Hint : Expand $\operatorname{Cov}(X-Y,X-Y)$ .

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks very much for your help!